# union and join columns of the same table

Tags: oracle9i

I have a table with columns

```
date_1,date_2,date_3,
text_1,text_2,text_3.
```

I want to write a query to fetch

```
date_1 union date_2 union date_3 as date 
and text_1 union text_2 union text_3 as text.
```

I am able to union them separately but how do I join them?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the rows unioned, then you could do..

```
select date1, text1 from table_1
union
select date2, text2 from table_2
union
select date3, text3 from table_2
```

If you want the lists to be joined seperately, what is the condition for the join? Could you povide more relevant data perhaps?